# About duration of stay in UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas, visa-expiration

In short term C type visa Overstay is the allowed duration a six month stay or the visa expiry date?

Because the duration of stay is 180 days. I entered UK at September 27; my visa will be expire 12 October.
How Long I can stay in UK in this case?

If I stay after 12 October is it overstay or I can stay maximum 180 days from the date of entry even if the visa expires.
What is over stay in this case please let me know .

Comment: What was the start date of your visa? It’s very unusual to get a UK Standard Visitor visa with a validity period of less than 6 months

Comment: You have created two accounts ([Abdul](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/104227/abdul) and [Abdul](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/104232/abdul)).  You can [merge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them, in which case you will be able to post comments on your own questions and on the answers to those questions.  You will also be able to edit your question.

Comment: @Abdul Not leaving on or before 12 October = overstaying unless you are eligible to apply to extend your visa and do so before your current visa expires.

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, as in the Schengen area, you may only remain while your visa is valid.  Six months is the maximum duration of validity for a standard visitor visa, but if your visa has a shorter period of validity you must respect that.

If your visa has been issued for a shorter period, you can [apply to extend it](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/extend-your-visa). The total duration of your visit may not exceed six months.  Like many UK immigration fees, this is ludicrously expensive, costing £993 for the extension and £19.20 for biometrics processing, for a total of £1012.20.

Comment: If the OP does indeed have a short duration visa, the circumstances in which such a visa would be issued are here https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf#page39